# Unable to use a modified word template in RStudio knitr

Tags: r, ms-word, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Unable to use a modified Word template from Rstudio using Knit Word from Rstudio. Rstudio and required packages were installed and updated this week.  Running OS X 10.10.5 and using Word 2011.  Simplified testing to  Yihui Xie's 113-externalization.rmd and 113-foo.R and have followed his Vimeo video https://vimeo.com/110804387 on this subject.  In all cases, knitting the RMD file uses the default formats and not the modified template stored as template.docx.  I have tried putting copies in all locations in the project directory without success.

````
#113-externalization.Rmd
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
     word_document: 
     reference_doc: "template.docx"
---

# Code Externalization

```{r cache=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk('113-foo.R')
```

The following two chunks are from the external R script `113-foo.R`:

```{r test-a}
```
```{r test-b}
```
#code for 113-foo.R
# ---- test-a ----
1 + 1
x = rnorm(10)

# ---- test-b ----
mean(x)
sd(x)
````

Search found [Changing word template for knitr in Rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440007/changing-word-template-for-knitr-in-rmarkdown), but that failed to locate the modified template at any location in the project directory.

Comment: In the video he uses `reference_docx:`. Does that make the difference?

Comment: Yes and No.   I changed to reference_docx: and received a failure message.   Entered the text as

Comment: Well for me it does work using `reference_docx: word-template.docx`. Make sure your indentation in the YAML header is correct (check the video again).

Comment: I just tried it: doesnt matter if you use `reference_doc` or `reference_docx`. I guess it is the indentation then...

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure the indentation of the YAML header is the problem. Change it to:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  word_document: 
    reference_docx: "template.docx"
---
```

---

I also just found out for myself that it does not make a difference if you use `reference_doc` or `reference_docx`.

Comment: Many thanks.  Can' find any documentation on this but it appears to be the solution.

Comment: The documentation is here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format.html#style_reference

Answer (score 0):

Tried changing the reference thanks to Martin Schmelzer's comment and accidentally hit upon the solution.
Working YAML HEADER

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
     word_document:
      reference_doc: "template.docx"
---
```

FAILING YAML HEADERS.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
     word_document:
      reference_doc: "template.docx"
---
```

Putting everything in a single line also fails. I haven't found the documentation yet but it appears that a CR and or an indent is needed between the various entries in the output line.